# How to verifying input from SWT Text widget and assign to variable?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, actionlistener

This SWT program has a Group called mBuy, which includes Text Field to enter a stock's buy price. Once the calculate button is pressed and event listener is activated, I want to assign whatever content is inside this text field to a variable, which I have initialized here.

```
final Text tmp0 = new Text(mBuy, SWT.SINGLE);
tmp0.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

// Calculate Button
Button tmp3 = new Button(mBuy, SWT.PUSH);
tmp3.setText("Calculate");
tmp3.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, true));

// if calculate button is pressed
tmp3.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        //take the decimal value inside textbox 
        bPrice=Double.parseDouble(tmp0.getText());
        // don't show buy menu anymore
        mBuy.dispose();

    }
});
```

Comment: Have you even tried to use google for that?

Comment: Don't you think that was the first thing that I tried?

Answer (score 3):

It's just `tmp0.getText()`. You should look at the [Javadocs for SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/javadoc.php).

Comment: This is wrong. I get an error because the string that tmp0 produces is NULL. I know you have to use verifylistener to verify input for SWT, so you can't just use getText(). Any other ideas? I posted my updated code that gives me the NULL error.

Comment: Then this looks like a bug in SWT. It should never return null: "The text for a text widget is the characters in the widget, or an empty string if this has never been set." You also can use `getText` in a `VerifyListener`, it'll return the current text.